# How to fix Listview scrolling jank when loading images from network

Tags: flutter

I am loading images using Image.network for each item in a list using the following code:

```
Image getEventImageWidget(AustinFeedsMeEvent event) {
return event.photoUrl.isNotEmpty ?
          Image.network(
            event.photoUrl,
            width: 77.0,
            height: 77.0,
          ) : Image.asset(
            'assets/ic_logo.png',
            width: 77.0,
            height: 77.0,
          );
}
```

When I scroll up and down, the list sometimes hangs when loading the images. Is there a way I can load the images on a background thread? What can I do to help fix scrolling performance?

NOTE: When I looked back at this, I found that the images that I was using were really large.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two was to speed up the rendering of your ListView of images.

The first is to set the `cacheExtent` property to a larger value in your ListView constructor.  This property controls how much offscreen widgets are rendered, and will help by causing the rendering to start a bit sooner.

The second is to pre-cache your images using [`precacheImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html). Flutter has an in-memory cache, so it is generally to necessary to cache everything to disk to get good read performance.  Instead, you can ask Flutter to download these images ahead of time so that they are ready when the widget is built.  For example, if you have a list of urls of your image, then in an `initState` method you could ask Flutter to cache all of them.

```
final List<String> imageUrls = [ /* ... */ ];

@override
void initState() {
  for (String url in imageUrls) {
    precacheImage(new NetworkImage(url), context);
  }
  super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure your images are not very heavy? Check the size of the images first.
Also you can use the package named: [cache_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image)

It's very simple :

```
new Image(image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(url))
```

**UPDATE (Package was updated)**

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use:

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
  placeholder: 'assets/ic_logo.png',
  image: event.photoUrl,
  height: 77.0,
  width: 77.0,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  fadeInDuration: new Duration(milliseconds: 100),
),
```

but yeah, per diegoveloper, you sure your images aren't huge?  Listview has no problem rendering anything that's close to reasonable in size.

Comment: The issue was large images.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stateful Widget that creates the ListView with placeholder images, then have it have an async method you call after `build()` that loads the images from network (one by one) and then changes the state of the previously mentioned widget to replace the placeholder with the correct image. As a bonus, you can create a cache that stores the images so they don't have to be downloaded each time the ListView enters scope (here you would have the async method look in the cache for the image and if it doesn't find it there, download it).

As a side note, this would obviously require giving each of the images in the ListView an index.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue, when there are large images in the list.

To resolve the issue, I shrink the image size by `ResizeImage`.

```
// Specify the widht of the ListView. 
// If it is unknown, it is reasonable to use device width.
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

Image(
  image: ResizeImage(NetworkImage('http://xxxxx/huge-image.jpg'),
   width: width),
);
```